# Difference between neutron flux and fluence?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I was skimming through the [ITER Technical Basis](https://www-pub.iaea.org/MTCD/publications/PDF/ITER-EDA-DS-24.pdf) and in page 16 of the PDF, under the subheading "Design Requirements", it says that the engineering requirements are:

[image: screenshot]

I'm confused because these units do not match [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_flux) units for neutron flux and fluence:

- Neutron flux: $\text{cm}^{-2}\text{s}^{-1}$
- Neutron fluence: $\text{cm}^{-2}$

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is" a" in this context?

Comment: I don't know that either; Searching through the booklet for 'MWa' doesn't reveal anything interesting either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As about first parameter it seems that specification is talking about irradiance flux density. Neutron flux can be extracted from it like that : $$\Phi _ n = \frac {J} {E_n} $$ Where $J$ is irradiance flux density $[\text{W} /\text{m} ^2]$ and $E_n$ is neutron average kinetic energy.

As about second parameter I'm not sure. In one page above in other formula they give that $a$ is plasma minor radius. In such case their "neutron fluence" will have dimensions of $[\text {W} /\text{m} ]$, to which closest interpretation would be spectral flux density usually measured in $[\text{W} /\text{nm} ]$ - radiation power per unit wavelength. But I doubt that variable $a$ has same context as in page above. Probably it does not. Then it's not clear what they had in mind.

Comment: Paired with @Jean's answer, I think you've hit the nail on the head, One final question before I mark this as accepted: What is $\Phi_n$? A single word answer will suffice, thank you.

Comment: @Krish It's a neutron flux - number of neutrons crossing unit area per unit time span. I. E. definition of it is exactly as in wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2):

Fluence is the time  integrated flux .
Here  , replace " a "  for annual  , by " y "  for year .
You obtain a more known unity   :  0.3 MW-y / ...